# How to find day difference between two dates using jsp?

Tags: jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Current Date & Time</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Display Current Date & Time</h1></center>
    <%
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        out.println("Current Date is:"+currentDate);
        String txtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(currentDate);
        out.println("Current Date in text format is:"+txtDate);
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://retail:3306/rs","RS","orbisindia");
            Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from retail_inventory") ;
            while (rs1.next()){
                out.println(txtDate.toString());
                out.println((rs1.getString(6).toString()));
                out.println((txtDate.toString())  - (rs1.getString(6).toString()) );
            %><br><%
            }
            conn.close(); 
        catch(Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: String txtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").format(currentDate);

Comment: 1. out.println(txtDate.toString());
  2.  out.println((rs1.getString(6).toString()));
    3.    out.println((txtDate.toString())  - (rs1.getString(6).toString()) );

Comment: 1 and 2 line are working but 3 line is not working

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding comments to give more details (then delete those comments, thanks). You're converting the dates you have to strings, then try to subtract strings from each other - not sure what you're expecting to happen, but it's definitely not a numeric operation. Check the use of `Calendar` for calculations on days, for example. Or you can subtract two `Date`s (or their milliseconds-since-1970) from each other, resulting in the millisecond difference between the two dates - which should be easy to convert to days.